# Template iterator, no STL

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how much this fits in here and I'm kinda new to C++ but I have to make an ADT over a dynamic array/linked list with iterators. My question is, is there a way to make this iterator a template so it could work for both the dynamic array and the linked list or I have to make 2 different implementations for a class Iterator?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
template<typename Container>
class Iterator {
private:
    Container *cont;
    int pos;

public:
    Iterator();
    Iterator(const Container& c);
    ~Iterator();
    bool isValid();
    void operator++();
    void operator--();
    Element getCurrent();

};
```

Now clearly, it has no idea what Element is and that's my problem. Is there any way to have getCurrent() to return the element from  the current position?
Is this going anywhere?

Comment: Of course, you can always provide completely different specializations for `Iterator<List>` and `Iterator<Array>`, but I don't see much point in it. Otherwise it will heavily depend on what is common between your `List` and `Array`.

Comment: It depends on the containers, if they have functions to get an element from a specified position.

Comment: It would make more sense to make the iterators independent, but behave identically, like how the STL is designed, and then make the algorithms templates.

Comment: So I should make 2 independent iterators for a more safer approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in c++ 14 you can do this :

```
template<typename Container>
class Iterator {
private:
    Container *cont;
    int pos;

public:
    Iterator();
    Iterator(const Container& c);
    ~Iterator();
    bool isValid();
    void operator++();
    void operator--();
    auto getCurrent(); // the return type is automatically generated

};
```

but in c++11 
you have to erase the return type
so getCurrent(); must return a void *
and use reinterpret_cast(getCurrent());

implementation correction: (what i think)

```
template<typename Container>
class Iterator {
private:
    Container *cont;
    int currentPos;
    int beginPos;
    int endPos;  
public:
    Iterator();
    Iterator(const Container& c,int endpos)currentPos{0},beginPos{0},endPos{endpos};
    ~Iterator();
    void operator++();
    void operator--(); 
    auto& getCurrent()const;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh you're right. I forgot about auto. But does my representation look any good?

Comment: I would prefer to make `getCurrent` a template, so the type to cast it into can be passed in as the template parameter. Or just do something so I can compute the correct type from `Container`. (e.g. give the containers a `value_type` or make a traits class)

Comment: @Katie44 see implementation correction for what i change to you code.

Comment: @Hurkyl in c++14 it's not needed

Comment: @Hurky I cant make another template for getCurrent(), it must be a part of the iterator. I can either go on c++14 and make the return type auto, or make 2 implementations for iterator.
gregoryboero.teyssier thank you

Comment: @Katie: you can make member functions templates.